# how to toggle text of DOM element on click

Tags: jquery, html

As the title says I'm fairly new to JQuery programming. Here is a little test JSFiddle I set up:

http://jsfiddle.net/LQNmK/10/

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

     $("#testing1").show();
 });

 $(".testbutton").live("click", function () {
     $("#testing1 p").toggle("showorhide");
 });
```

On here I am basically doing a showorhide or a div.

My question is I want the button to say Show when it is hidden and vice versa. What would be a nice simple way for this to be shown?

Comment: Don't use `live`, use `on` or just `click`.  `live` is deprecated and has been removed entirely as of 1.9.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  $(".testbutton").live("click", function () {
     $("#testing1 p").toggle("showorhide",function(){
         $(".testbutton").val($("#testing1 p").is(':visible')?'Hide':'Show');
     });
 });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LQNmK/24/

Comment: Thanks a lot for this one, I personally understood this one most and have saved this into my JSFiddle/

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way would be to check whether the content is visible or not:

```
$(document).on("click", ".testbutton", function(ev) {
    var content = $("#testing1 p");
    content.toggle("showorhide");
    var text = content.is(":visible") ? "hide" : "show";
    $(this).val(text);
});
```

Note, that I've changed (depracated) `live` to `on`.

Comment: Should really cache `$("#testing1 p")`.  +1 for maintaining the event delegation though.

Comment: @JamesMontagne As you wish. :)

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
 $(".testbutton").on("click", function () {
     $("#testing1 p").toggle("showorhide");
     $(".testbutton").text($('#testing1 p').is(':visible') ? 'Hide' : 'Show');
 });
```

As pointed out, use "on" instead of "live" as it has be removed from the current version of jQuery

Comment: Should be noted that you have removed the event delegation.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
var status = $("#testing1 p").is(":visible");
var btn  = $(".testbutton");
if(status === true) {
  btn.attr('value','hide');
} else {
btn.attr('value','show');
}
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LQNmK/20/

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to use two buttons, one hidden by default, and `.toggle()` them both when either one is clicked. This makes it easier to tweak how you'd like either button to appear to the user -- just change the HTML, and leave the JavaScript alone.

HTML:

```
<input class="testbutton btn" type="button" value="Hide"/>
<input class="testbutton btn" style="display:none" type="button" value="Show"/>
```

JS:

```
 $(".testbutton").on("click", function () {
     $('.testbutton').toggle(); // flip them both
     $("#testing1 p").toggle("showorhide");
 });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/UeuQm/

Answer (score 0):

I'd personally suggest:

```
$("#testing1").show();

$(".testbutton").on("click", function () {
    $(this).val(function (i, v) {
        return v.toLowerCase() == 'show' ? 'Hide' : 'Show';
    });
    $('#testing1 p').toggle();
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/LQNmK/21/).